# Nativescript custom fonts issue

Tags: css, fonts, nativescript

I am trying to get custom fonts working in Nativescript, and hve them in the src/fonts folder at root. I have looked at other questions on SO, but not solved it, the css is below, and it is a display font just for the action bar title, not used anywhere else.

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Trade Winds';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Trade Winds'), local('TradeWinds'),
       url('src/fonts/trade-winds-v8-latin-regular.ttf') format('ttf'), /* Safari, Android, IOS*/
}
.action-label {
font-family: 'Trade Winds', 'trade-winds';
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
color:blue;
}

have also tried variations of the path but not working. Only testing in Android at the moment. Thanks
```

Comment: You don't have to define font face with NativeScript. When you specify the font family, the first name shall be the postscript name (`Trade Winds`), followed by the file name (`trade-winds`, your font file name should be like `trade-winds.ttf` in this case).

Comment: I tried this, but no joy :                                                                                    
.action-label {
font-family: 'Trade Winds', 'trade-winds';
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
color:blue;
src: local('Trade Winds'), local('TradeWinds'),
       url('src/fonts/trade-winds.ttf') format('ttf'), /* Safari, Android, IOS*/
}

Comment: Are you trying to use icon on AcrionBar?

Comment: Yes am, not showing though, app is still loading on emulator, and works, but console shows res://icon error, and the font not show

Comment: So that seems to be the issue. You can not apply font family on AcrionBar yet. Use an ActionView and place an image or label to use font.

Comment: Ok will try that Thanks